# Update field with Word Count from SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL in MSSQL:

```
SELECT
(LEN(article) - LEN(REPLACE(article, ' ', ''))) + 1
FROM articles
```

How do I take these results and update the field 'wordcount' in the table 'articles'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just put this expression in an `update`:

```
update articles a
     set wordcount = (LEN(article) - LEN(REPLACE(article, ' ', ''))) + 1;
```